# How to insert inputs to database in Laravel using ajax with jquery.serializeJSON package?

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, laravel

I need your help how can I insert the input data using ajax? Side note I am using jquery.serializeJSON package to get json object input from the user. It will show error 419 when I submit it. Here is my html code bellow

```
<form  id="myform">
    @csrf
<input type="text" name="name" value="Jake Zyrus">
  <input type="text" name="description[name]" value="John Smith"/>
  <input type="text" name="description[job]"  value="Legendary Pirate"/>
  <input type="text" name="description[car]"  value="Delorean"/>
  <button type="submit" >Add</button>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

       var employee = $('#myform').serializeJSON();
       var employees = JSON.stringify(employee);
       
      
      $('#myform').submit(function(){

        $.ajax({

            type: "POST",
            url: "/insert",
            data: employees,
            success: function(response){
                alert("Data Save");
            },
            error: function(error){
                alert("Didnt Save");

            }

        });

      });

     
    });

   
</script>
```

While this is my controller file

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\job;
class JobController extends Controller
{
        public function create(Request $request){
            $jobs = new job;
            $jobs->name = $request->input('name');
            $jobs->description[] = $request->input('description');
            $jobs->save();
            return redirect('home');
        }
}
```

And lastly this is the Model App file

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class job extends Model
{
    //

    protected $table = 'jobs';
    protected $casts = [
        'description' => 'array'
    ];
```

}

Thanks in advance for the reply. It would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using ajax request to save data, you can access serialized form data directly with like `$request->name`.

Comment: You mean $jobs->name = $request->name;? Still the same it shows some error